# Any way to avoid duplicate code for mut not mut reference inside struct?

Tags: reference, rust, mutability

Here what I want to achieve:

```
trait Foo {
    fn readonly(&self) -> i32;
    fn modify(&mut self, val: i32);
}

struct FooWrapper<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo,
}

impl<'a> FooWrapper<'a> {
    fn readonly(&self) -> i32 {
        self.foo.readonly()
    }

    fn modify(&mut self, val: i32) {
        self.foo.modify(val);//!!!
    }
}
```

As input I got `&Foo` and `&mut Foo`, like:
`fn func(a: &Foo, b: &mut Foo)`.

I want then wrap them inside `FooWraper`, and use it's methods
to work with `Foo`.

But  as you see compiler not allow code marked with `//!!!`.

Any way to fix this without code duplication like:

```
struct FooWrapper<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo,
}
struct FooWrapperMut<'a> {
    foo: &'a mut Foo,
}
impl<'a> FooWrapper<'a>..
impl<'a> FooWrapperMut<'a>..
```

?

Comment: *But as you see compiler not allow code* — you need to include the complete compiler error. It is not acceptable to simply state that an error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Just make `foo` a mutable reference. Then it can be borrowed either mutably or immutably.

```
struct FooWrapper<'a> {
    foo: &'a mut Foo,
}
```

A `&mut T` reference can always be coerced to a `&T`.

If you wanted to provide minimal functionality for an immutable reference and some additional methods if you able to get a mutable reference, you could maybe split it out with type parameter:

```
trait Foo {
    fn readonly(&self) -> i32;
    fn modify(&mut self, val: i32);
}

struct FooWrapper<T> {
    foo: T,
}

impl <'a> FooWrapper<&'a Foo> {
    fn readonly(&self) -> i32 {
        self.foo.readonly()
    }
}

impl <'a> FooWrapper<&'a mut Foo> {
    fn modify(&mut self, val: i32) {
        self.foo.modify(val); //
    }
}
```

Now you can supply the type parameter to be either `&mut Foo` or just `&Foo`, depending on what you have.

Comment: "Just make foo a mutable reference" I cann't, if I get `&Foo` as input how can I construct `&mut Foo` from it? See `func` as example.

Comment: You probably need to include more code in order to explain your problem, and to show that it is different from the duplicate (if it is).